# UITableViewCell text field value in another method

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitableview

```
-(void)sendcomment:(UIButton *)sender{

    NSLog(@" send commment server");

    thirdviewcellTableViewCell *dja =[[thirdviewcellTableViewCell alloc] init];
    NSString *vga = [[NSString alloc] init];
    vga=dja.celltext;
    NSLog(@"comment value is %@",vga);
    NSLog(@"comment cell value is %@",dja.celltext);
}
```

Comment: In this method, you are creating a local textField and trying to take its text. But it should be empty. You should hold textField with global value for that class.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)sendcomment:(UIButton *)sender
 {
 UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
 NSIndexPath *indexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
 UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexpath];
  // If you have text field
 UITextField *textfiled = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:yourtextfeildtagvlaue];

// NSString *vga = textfiled.text
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the cell hold the button, you can do this:

```
-(void)sendcomment:(UIButton *)sender{

    // 1. get the position the button you clicked
    CGPoint correctedPoint = [sender convertPoint:button.bounds.origin toView:self.tableView];

    // 2. find the cell via the position
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:correctedPoint];
    thirdviewcellTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];;

    // 3. then you can get the TextField value
    NSString *textFieldValue = [[NSString alloc] init];
    textFieldValue = cell.celltext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you get your cell using cell's hierarchy

```
 -(void)sendcomment:(UIButton *)sender
     {
     UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
     NSIndexPath *indexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender.superview.superview;// get cell using view hierarchy 
      // If you have text field
     UITextField *textfiled = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:yourtextfeildtagvlaue];
    // NSString *vga = textfiled.text
     }

*
```

Answer (score 0):

In your action method you can Find Your TextField as below :
You can find IndexPath from SuperView.
See below Code.

```
UIView *superView = btn.superview;

while (![superView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    superView = superView.superview;
}

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)superView;
```

You will get `UITextField` object from `cell.yourTextFeld` .
And you can use TextField as per your requirement.